# Changing bulleted item in CSS to fa fa-heart with \f004

Tags: html, css

I am editing the CSS on my site, and want to make the bullets that appear next to my "likes" appear as a Font Awesome Heart ([link](https://fontawesome.com/icons/heart?style=regular))

I use the following code in my CSS:

```
span.dots ::before { 
font-family: 'FontAwesome';
content: '\f004';
    font-size: 15px;
color: #f00;
}
```

The class of the `<span>` is dots, so thats what I am targeting.

The heart appears fine, but it's a full heart, not a bordered hear with a hollowed out center. To get the style I want usually you have to switch the class to "fas fa-heart" but let's assume all I can do is edit the CSS.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://fontawesome.com/start click the [regular] button, see the stylesheet links.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the the entire FontAwesome family installed? If you do, then it could be a font-weight issue. Try:

```
span.dots ::before { 
font-family: 'FontAwesome';
content: '\f004';
font-weight:400;
    font-size: 15px;
color: #f00;
}
```

If you take a look at the FontAwesome CSS file it tells you which style to use if you have the entire font family in the css.